# Sliding text with CSS3 animation / transition

Tags: css, animation

I wanted to know how to make this kind of animation: https://dimes.io/

I am trying to figure out how they did this headings and paragraph animation. However, I did some research "under the hood" and found those css snippets

```
  .ani-1s-200ms {
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms 200ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 1000ms 200ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transition: all 1000ms 200ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.ani-1s-400ms {
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms 400ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 1000ms 400ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transition: all 1000ms 400ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.ani-1s-600ms {
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms 600ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 1000ms 600ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transition: all 1000ms 600ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}

.ani-1s-800ms {
  -webkit-transition: all 1000ms 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 1000ms 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
  transition: all 1000ms 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
}
```

When I try to add similar or the same css and apply those classes to my element the animation is not made. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Those aren't **animations** they're transitions that happen when there is a state change. Offhand, I suspect they are also Javascript hooks

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for a update. As you said, most probably there are some Javascript hooks because I can not figure it out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

> transition: **all** 1000ms 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);

The **all** value tells that all (animateable) CSS values should be included in the transition. You also need to specify values starting/ending values.

```
.cls {
    width: 100px;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.cls.animate {
    width: 200px;
}
```

I'm animating here from 100px to 200px when i add the `.animate` class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what animation you are referring to, but you are using transition with the wrong arguments:

```
transition: <property> <duration> <timing-function> <delay>;
```

So instead of `all 1000ms 200ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);` it would be one duration value `all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);`. Can't say if something else is wrong in your code though since you didn't provide it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the co-founder of Dimes and wrote that code.
I wrote it out like that just to save time and markup.
As @dominic-tobias and other's have said it's only a transition i.e the timing function (you can see the timing differences in the code).

@wintercounter's answer shows how it should be used if you were to write it in full.

There are many ways to achieve the effect I have but the easiest way for you is probably use something like Dan Eden's [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)